# Does aacdecoder aacplayer support links ending with :0000/?

Tags: android, aac

I am trying to play music from `http://s1.slotex.pl:7116/` link by aacplayer according to this [link](http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/wiki/HowToBuildProject). Sometimes I have links which ends with `/listen.pls`. However I get nulls while starting.
Does anyone knows how to fix it?

```
12-11 13:07:17.160  32005-32080/com.example.radiochrzescijaninpl E/AACPlayer﹕ playAsync():
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot start native decoder
            at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.Decoder.start(Decoder.java:217)
            at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.playImpl(AACPlayer.java:351)
            at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:313)
            at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:283)
            at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer$1.run(AACPlayer.java:248)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: `listen.pls` is a [playlist file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_(file_format)) sometimes used for internet radio streams (or local playlists). Are you sure that your decoder is capable of parsing these files? If not, you'll have to find or implement a PLS parser.

Comment: I've chanded radio link. Well, listen.pl has the same url `http://s1.slotex.pl:7116/`